# operator TYPE () and taking the address of an object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wrapper, atl, bstr

The ATL class [CComBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zh7x9w3f.aspx) has a `BSTR` member `m_str` and an `operator BSTR ()` which returns `m_str`.

Now, if a function takes a `BSTR *` as argument, is it ok to pass the address of a `CComBSTR`?

```
CComBSTR path;
// signature is IzFileFinder::GetDir(CY index, LPBSTR path)
fileFinder->GetDir(INT64toCURRENCY(i), &path);
```

The compiler doesn't complain, but if it really is ok, why does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing an address of `CComBSTR`, but an address of its `m_str` member. `CComBSTR` happens to provide, among other things, an `operator&()` that returns `&m_str`.